# Unexpected Token `:' while defining QML signal parameter type

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to familiarize myself with QML. I am following [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-tutorial1.html) Qt provide tutorial, but have run into a problem.

**Problem:**

While creating the [Cell.qml](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-tutorial2.html) file, I am required to create a clicked signal, where the single parameter named `cellColor` is defined as a `color` type (*if I understand this correctly*)

> ../QMLTest/Cell.qml:6 Unexpected token `:'

The code snippet in question from `Cell.qml` is:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: container
    property alias cellColor: rectangle.color
    signal clicked(cellColor: color)                   <-----Problem - line 6

    width: 40; height: 25
    //...
}
```

Since QML uses Javascript, I figured I'll try this, which worked:

```
signal clicked(var cellColor)
```

*One obvious drawback is you lose the defined type (based on my assumption earlier).*

**Question:**

Why did the provided signal code not work, and is there any drawback to using the `var` keyword instead of defining the type?

**Update**

*Added after answer was accepted.*

I should also have mentioned, I am using Qt Creator 4.10.0 with Qt 5.13.1 (MSVC 32bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is new in Qt 5.14. It's following TypeScript syntax and the way to go for the upcoming QML 3. With older Qt versions, one gets the error message that you mentioned. The classical and so far still supported syntax would be

```
signal clicked(color cellColor)
```

The `name: type` syntax isn't even mentioned yet in the [Qt documentation about QML signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#adding-signals-to-custom-qml-types).